# woocommerce how to add images at "has been added to your cart"?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

woocommerce how to add images at  "has been added to your cart"?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to your 
wordpress\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-cart-functions.php

find the code

```
} else {
        $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ), esc_html__( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
    }
```

replace it with below code

```
} else {
             $product_meta = get_post_meta($product_id);
             $img = wp_get_attachment_image(($product_meta['_thumbnail_id'][0]), 'thumbnail');
        $message   = sprintf( "$img".'<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ), esc_html__( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
    }
```

it will look like this http://prntscr.com/f3hpsx

Comment: You should not change core files to get the effect, if you forget you made this change you'll lose it next time WooCommerce updates.

If you solved the problem yourself, can you answer your own question here rather than just accepting another one?

I'm looking for a solution myself :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via `wc_add_to_cart_message` filter from woocommerce.

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'adding_image_to_cart_message' );

function adding_image_to_cart_message() {
  global $woocommerce;
  $return_to = get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('shop'));
  $imgpath = 'add your image path here';
  $message = sprintf('<img src="%s"/><a href="%s" class="button wc-forwards">%s</a> %s', $imgpath , $return_to, __('Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce'), __('has been added to your cart.', 'woocommerce') );
  return $message;
}
```

Add your image path to `$imgpath` variable.

Comment: i need display product images